# how to compare a jsonb object that is a superset of another

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'd like to be able to perform a check on jsonb objects with postgres where:

```
x = '{"a": 1, "b": 2}'
y = '{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}'
z = '{"a": 1, "b": 4, "c": 3}'
```

`jsonb_similar(x, y)` gives true.
`jsonb_similar(x, z)` gives false.

what is the best way to write `jsonb_similar`?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

Comment: I think you are looking for the "contains" operator, e.g. `'{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}'::jsonb @> ''{"a": 1, "b": 2}'::jsonb`

Comment: oh man. I was looking at the functions and completely forgot about the operators. I'll be happy to accept an answer.